# Is it possible to deduct amount for monthly app uses through In-App purchase from user/customer?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have one iOS app and want to deduct some amount through In-App purchase for every month as a maintenance charges. Example: I want to give my app as a free trail for first one month and after that I want to deduct $2 for every month as a monthly maintenance charges. Is it possible through In-App Purchase? Please advice me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Subscriptions is what you may be looking for

Comment: @Striker, Is subscription required any downloadable things? as I don't any content or other things to download from App.

Comment: You can implement it as an access to your app's features. So if your users are subscribed, they should have access to all the content. Furthermore, for apple you need to provide a clear description and an image to show the difference. Additionally, you need to have a restore feature for example when users have multiple devices or has bought a new device.

Comment: A better explanation usually at apple sites: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH2-SW3

Comment: @Striker Thank you very much. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that Apple would allow you a monthly maintenance charges just for using App. Subscription means you would unlock some content (which is paid), until user is in subscription period.

Still, just put a logic to detect whether user has been using your App since a month. You can do this by storing date in defaults. If it is more than one month, present user a subscription page with pricing.

Specify everything in details in review notes to make App reviewer understand well. If they don't have any issue with that, you will be done.

Comment: Is not possible to achieve without providing the content in iTunes store?

Comment: I want to deduct amount from user through In-App Purchase without adding any content in the iTunes Store. Is it possible?